# Post not being reopened after being edited as suggested

Tags: discussion

I edited my original post to avoid it attracting opinion but it is still not being reopened. What does it take to get it opened? I need some help to get it opened please. The post is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733586/what-strategies-can-i-use-to-debug-a-concurrent-system-built-using-scala-akka .

Comment: So now this post has a rating of -2 and my point about SE now, you can't even ask for advice or help without being getting smashed with down votes. It's true what others are saying about SE on the internet, it's slowly being killed by trigger happy moderators.

Comment: Consider that the down votes might have been the result of the way you've worded the title, "Post not being reopened after being edited as suggested".  A more humble approach, such as "What else do I need to improve in my post to get it reopened?", would likely yield up votes, at least from what I've seen from past interactions with people with closed posts. Hope this helps.

Comment: @jmort253, there's nothing wrong with the title in my opinion, it's just a plain factual statement of the situation, nothing more, nothing less. Do not read too much into it other than its plain meaning.

Comment: Sure, and I wanted to add that I don't think this should have been down voted... the wording isn't negative or filled with a sense of entitlement. I've seen worse. Just, hoping to give some helpful feedback. Your request seemed genuine...

Comment: @jmort253, yep thanks for the feedback - I will keep it mind. Yes, my request/post is very genuine. In fact, debugging concurrent systems is extremely difficult as you may know. I wanted to know from the SE community who use Akka was what techniques they have in place to deal with this issue. Since I am about to embark on building an Akka based system, I really wanted to reach and get some answers to that question to help me. But the rest, as they say, is history. AFAIK, this question has never been asked on SE before, so to get smashed left, right, and centre was very disappointing.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that if it was a "new" question as it is, it would still be closed as "too broad", which is why people decided to leave it closed. I think it would have been through the review process -- let me see if I can find the review (10k users?).

Questions asking for a number of "proven best strategies" tends to produce list-like answers which could be made up, and most cannot be directly objectively assessed as being better than one another. Stack Overflow is particularly stringent on this.

Comment: What if changed it to proven strategy? Would that be in line with the rules? I've actually seen other posts which violate this rule so it's not uniformly applied. That is what is confusing.

Comment: @I.K.: indeed, some have been closed but others haven't. If you could define in some way what makes it "proven", then that might be more objective.

Comment: Thanks for checking. This all is a bit hit-and-miss really. It would be far better of the people that put posts on hold gave an OP some feedback on why they *still* think the post is not allowed after being re-edited. Otherwise it's all down to mind reading and I'm no good at that ;)

Comment: @I.K.: note also that the rules have changed slightly since most of those questions were asked, which may make it seem a bit out of place.

Comment: Is it ok if I repost this as new question but modified as you suggest? Or will I get smashed for that?

Comment: @I.K.: you'd probably be downvoted more for that.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that even when a question does not invite opinion anymore it still can't be asked. That's bad.

Comment: @I.K.: not necessarily, it depends on the question. In this case, as said in the help centre, it's off topic as multiple techniques would be equally valid. The reason I said that you'd get downvoted more is because it's frowned upon to reask the same question, even if you think it was unfair that your question was closed.

Comment: @I.K. - I can't comment on the motivation of the reviewers, but this is how it was reviewed in the Reopen Votes queue: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4464786 . Three of the four reviewers thought it should remain closed.

Comment: @BradLarson, thank you. I have deleted the original post as I wanted to spend no more energy on it on SE. I asked the same question on the Akka Google group and I got some good answers. What really irritates me is that some of these moderators don't even specialise in the technology I was querying about (I checked their profiles). It's just blind moderating IMO and it's really reflecting badly on SE. I am relatively new to SE but the behaviour of some moderators really needs to be questioned.

Comment: @I.K. - For the record, none of the people involved were actually moderators. We're denoted by diamonds after our names. These were normal community members who thought there was something wrong with the question that needed to be addressed. We don't require demonstrated expertise in relevant tags because issues with phrasing or being out of scope of the site can be judged by people from any background. It should be said that five community members (of diverse backgrounds) did vote to reopen your question before it was removed.